# How do i use quickbooks php-sdk to connect to quickbooks online in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, quickbooks-online

I tried using the sample app https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/OAuth2_PHP its working. but i have to integrate this in my laravel application. How do i include the php file in my controller. How do i change the code from php to laravel controller? I am pretty new to this so any help will be appreciated. And how do i use the php-SDK in my laravel?

i am not able to include the files in my blade. i tried this but its not working

```
<?php 
  $configs = include('./quickbooksconfig.php');
?>
<script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere-1.3.3.js">
 </script>
<script>
     var redirectUrl = '/employees/directory'
     intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({
             grantUrl:  redirectUrl,
             datasources: {
                  quickbooks : true,
                  payments : true
            },
             paymentOptions:{
                   intuitReferred : true
            }
     });
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

`composer require quickbooks/v3-php-sdk`

`composer update`

The classes from the SDK will then be available to your application as they would be with any other composer package.

More info can be found at https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK

Comment: I did that i didnt get how to connect to quickbooks using the SDk, Can you provide me an example.